# How to remove duplicate rows and create index in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have tab delimited files as shown below:

```
CNV_chr1_12623251_12632176  8925    3   RR123   XX
CNV_chr1_13398757_13402091  3334    4   RR123   YY
CNV_chr1_13398757_13402091  3334    4   RR224   YY
CNV_chr1_14001365_14004064  2699    1   RR123   YX
CNV_chr1_14001365_14004064  2699    1   RR224   YX
```

Columns $1 and $2 stay identical. In this case, i would need to remove the duplicate row by indexing with the value in 4th column. and add an additional $5 with number of strings separated by comma in $4. Sample output shown below:

```
CNV_chr1_12623251_12632176  8925    3   RR123    1    XX
CNV_chr1_13398757_13402091  3334    4   RR123,RR124    2    YY     
CNV_chr1_14001365_14004064  2699    1   RR123,RR224    2    YX
```

Any working soultion would be helpful.

Comment: Is the order of identical sequences random? You stated first and second column remains identical. What happens when the third column is different. Which one should be used?

Comment: keys to search are $1 and $2. it does not matter what other columns have. Below solution works but needs slight fixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '($1 in ar){ar[$1]=ar[$1]; br[$1]=br[$1]","$4; next;}
     {br[$1]=$4; $4="REPLACE_ME"; ar[$1]=$0}
     END{for(key in ar){c=split(br[key],s,",")
                        gsub("REPLACE_ME", br[key] FS c, ar[key])
                        print ar[key]}}' test.txt
```

The output:

```
CNV_chr1_14001365_14004064 2699 1 RR123,RR224 2 YX
CNV_chr1_13398757_13402091 3334 4 RR123,RR224 2 YY
CNV_chr1_12623251_12632176 8925 3 RR123 1 XX
```

For tab-delimited input just add `-F"\t"` to `awk`:

```
awk -F"\t" '($1 in ar){ar[$1]=ar[$1]; br[$1]=br[$1]","$4; next;}
            {br[$1]=$4; $4="REPLACE_ME"; ar[$1]=$0}
            END{for(key in ar){c=split(br[key],s,",")
                        gsub("REPLACE_ME", br[key] FS c, ar[key])
                        print ar[key]}}' test.txt
```

and get:

```
CNV_chr1_14001365_14004064 2699 1 RR123,RR224   2 YX
CNV_chr1_13398757_13402091 3334 4 RR123,RR224   2 YY
CNV_chr1_12623251_12632176 8925 3 RR123 1 XX
```

Comment: i kept the input file to be easy to understand. Now the code adds to the last column. I have made an edit where it has other  columns to be included.Any fix for this?